# Weird initialisation when override val met DelayedInit in Scala

Tags: scala, init

Following code's output makes me confused.

### code

```
object Test1 {
  trait A {
    val s: String = "A"
    println(s"s = $s")
  }

  abstract class B extends A with DelayedInit {

    override def delayedInit(body: => Unit) = {
      println("B " + "1" * 80)
      body
      println("B " + "2" * 80)
    }
  }

  abstract class C extends A with DelayedInit {

    override val s: String = "C"

    override def delayedInit(body: => Unit) = {
      println("C " + "1" * 80)
      body
      println("C " + "2" * 80)
    }
  }

  def main {
    println("-- new B begin")
    new B {
      println("new B context")
    }
    println("-- new B end")

    println("-- new C begin")
    new C {
      println("new C context")
    }
    println("-- new C end")
  }
}

object Test2 {
  trait A {
    def s: String = "A"
    println(s"s = $s")
  }

  abstract class B extends A with DelayedInit {

    override def delayedInit(body: => Unit) = {
      println("B " + "1" * 80)
      body
      println("B " + "2" * 80)
    }
  }

  abstract class C extends A with DelayedInit {

    override def s: String = "C"

    override def delayedInit(body: => Unit) = {
      println("C " + "1" * 80)
      body
      println("C " + "2" * 80)
    }
  }

  def main {
    println("-- new B begin")
    new B {
      println("new B context")
    }
    println("-- new B end")

    println("-- new C begin")
    new C {
      println("new C context")
    }
    println("-- new C end")
  }
}

println("Test1")
Test1.main
println("Test2")
Test2.main
```

### output

```
Test1
-- new B begin
s = A
B 11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
new B context
B 22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
-- new B end
-- new C begin
s = null
C 11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
C 22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
C 11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
new C context
C 22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
-- new C end
Test2
-- new B begin
s = A
B 11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
new B context
B 22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
-- new B end
-- new C begin
s = C
C 11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
new C context
C 22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
-- new C end
```

Tried both scala 2.10.2 & 2.11.0-M3.

In my understanding, Test1 should be the same as Test2. Here is two questions:

- Why DelayedInit has been called twice in Test1.C? There is not other class inherits the trait in the class hierarchy
- Why `s == null` in Test1.C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why DelayedInit has been called twice in Test1.C? There is not other class inherits the trait in the class hierarchy

This looks like a bug, try reporting it to Scala JIRA.

---

> Why `s == null` in `Test1.C`?

I'd say it's because the `val` in

```
override val s: String = "C"
```

is backed by an internal variable and this variable is initialized during the initializatino of `C`. And because `DelayedInit` doesn't capture `trait`s, the initialization for `A` is performed before `delayedInit`, that is before `C` and `val s` are initialized.

(It'd be interesting if someone posted decompiled Java code for the classes.)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I just fire a bug for it https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7677